# How to declare final Uri when use FirebaseStorage ?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I take a reference from FirebaseStorage , i want to save the value that is a image url , here is my code:

```
//FirebaseStorage
                String path="firememes/"+ UUID.randomUUID()+".png";
                StorageReference firememeRef=storage.getReference(path);

                StorageMetadata metadata=new StorageMetadata.Builder()
                        .setCustomMetadata("text","測試").build();

                 Uri url;
                UploadTask uploadTask=firememeRef.putBytes(bytes,metadata);
                StorageTask<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> taskSnapshotStorageTask = uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                         //it shows inner class , need to declared final
                         url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        Log.d("url>",url.toString());

                    }
                });
```

but when i change to final final Uri url; it shows Cannot a value to final variable 'url'

I want to get url.toString value and save it , how to set the global variable for Uri , any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the variable `url` inside the callback instead of outside the callback.

```
String path="firememes/"+ UUID.randomUUID()+".png";
StorageReference firememeRef=storage.getReference(path);

StorageMetadata metadata=new StorageMetadata.Builder()
        .setCustomMetadata("text","測試").build();

UploadTask uploadTask=firememeRef.putBytes(bytes,metadata);
StorageTask<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> taskSnapshotStorageTask = uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        //it shows inner class , need to declared final
        Uri url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
        Log.d("url>",url.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your responding , but i want to use the url value from outside , so i don't want the variable url inside the callback .   I try final Uri url that can't be define

Comment: Firebase task callbacks are all asynchronous.  You have to continue your work inside the callback.